# .Net Remoting : Windows Time change cause inoconsistcy state

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

[I am C++ developer now working on C# & .net  concept , So question may be very basic ]

I have a Server and Client based on .Net Remoting. Problem is that when  i change windows time , Session between client and server goes for a toss. I asked expert who delivered this code , According to him "In .NET Remoting, remote object lifetimes are based on lease
time. If the lease expires, the object is marked for GC" So when i change time lease expire and object is collected by GC.

Client and server both are running on same system.

Can some body suggest me what is going wrong and how to correct this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask you why do you need to change Windows time? Are you using NTP or what?

Comment: In my setup both client and server are on same machine. I am not using NTP.

Comment: You say _when i change windows time_: why do you need to do this?

Comment: When product shipped to customer.Customer is free to change time. We must not restrict him until unless its a critical domain software.

Comment: So basically it is end user who changes time in his computer.

Comment: Why remoting on same machine?

Comment: Add some extra exception handling and dispose logging to track what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a solution, but give it a try.
I think if you monitor for Windows time change you can close and restart your *remoting connection*.
I've found this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/c25aa6a5-3b4b-4a78-8867-a8de33bc33a4), hope is't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers. I found the root cause . Its a ingenious way where a thread from client time calls server at regular interval.

So this way Server knows that client is alive and keep lease time properly. Once time is changed. Ingenious way of calling server at regular interval goes for a toss. and on server side object is disposed.